# Are Double oven Kosher

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

I am planning on upgrading my kitchen but and I was wondering if a [double oven](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frigidaire-30-in-7-0-cu-ft-Double-Oven-Electric-Range-with-Self-Cleaning-Convection-Oven-in-Stainless-Steel-FGEF306TMF/203522845) could be kosher if 1 oven is just meat and one is just dairy.

Comment: Is there any transfer of steam/air between them?

Comment: Can you explain more about how this device works and why that might present a Kashrut problem? This way people can be sure to address your concerns and address the correct product.

Comment: My rabbi pointed me to this link regarding similar questions: https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/3704/oven-kashrus-101-using-the-same-oven-for-meat-dairy-fish-pareve/

Comment: http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=2375

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/6244

Comment: https://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/kosher-appliances/5290/sabbath-mode-faqs/

Comment: Short answer: CYLOR. Long answer: See your local orthodox Rabbi.